# EF code first attach and create proxy

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Let's say I have an entity Foo.

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}
```

When I get this entity from the db then I actually get a proxy and everything works as it should be.

But, can I attach Foo to DbContext and create the proxy manually so Bars would not return null after attaching it, but an actual collection of bars?

Meaning

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = 1 };
Context.Set<Foo>().Attach(foo);
foo = CreateProxyOf(foo);
var countOfBars = foo.Bars.Count();
```

Is there something like CreateProxyOf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is a way but instead of Foo's constructor you must use:

```
var set = Context.Set<Foo>();
var foo = set.Create();
foo.Id = 1;
set.Attach(foo);
var countOfBars = foo.Bars.Count();
```

Comment: YES! that what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

When you get all Foos or a single Foo you can tell EF to get bars at the same time. For example:

```
var foos = db.Foos.Include("Bars");

var foo = db.Foos.Include("Bars").Single(f => f.Id == 1);
```

More details on MSDN here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: what i actually ment was that, if i create var foo = new Foo{ Id = 1}. Then is it possible to attach it to DbContext so Bars would not be null, but actual result set.

Comment: Include returns a DbQuery<> object which doesn't seem to have a Find method on it. It is the DbSet<> class which has Find. Am I missing something. Is Find an extension method on DbQuery as well?

Comment: You are correct - no Find() method on DbQuery - just updated the code to reflect this.